# about accessing ios settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, widget, settings

I know there is no way to access/modify some system settings programmatically in iOS.
But then how comes there are so many widgets that for example turn wifi on/off?

I want to create a simple widget to switch between 2 sim cards in the phone, but I don't know if this is possible in iOS. Is it?

I have experience with Android and there you can access almost everything..

Comment: What do you mean by 'widget'? An app? If you use the correct words for things, people will understand your question better, and you have more chance of getting good help.

Comment: Well @occulus, English is not my mother tongue so I do my best writing my questions. By App I mean a mobile application. And by widget, I mean a desktop Widget for turning settings on/off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device needs to be jailbroken to do what you are asking.